# UpdatePanel refresh whole page (ASP.NET WebForm, migrated project)

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am working in ASP WebForm Project, it is legacy code, originaly it was made with VS 2008, but the team migrate it to VS 2015 and .NET 4.5.2. The problem is that I am trying to use an UpdatePanel to refresh a DataGrid every 10 seconds using a Timer as trigger, but it reload the whole page, even if i change the Timer by a Button the page is refreshed as well. I don't know if it happen for bad configuration of the ScriptManager or something else. 
This is my code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" AjaxFrameworkMode="Enabled"  runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="udt1" RenderMode="Block" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DataGrid ID="dg1" runat="server" CssClass="dataGrid" OnItemDataBound="dg1_ItemDataBound" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <SelectedItemStyle CssClass="SelectedItemStyle"></SelectedItemStyle>
            <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="AlternatingItemStyle"></AlternatingItemStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="ItemStyle"></ItemStyle>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle"></HeaderStyle>
            <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle"></FooterStyle>
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%"></ItemStyle>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <img id="imgOb" src="~/images/observacion.gif" style="cursor: hand; border: 0px;" runat="server" alt=""/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ID" HeaderText="No." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundColumn>
                <asp:TemplateColumn>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateColumn>
            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
        </asp:DataGrid>

        <asp:Timer ID="tmr1" runat="server" OnTick="tmr1_Tick" iterval="10000"></asp:Timer>
         <asp:Label ID="testlbl" runat="server" Text="1">1</asp:Label>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmr1" EventName="Tick" />
     </Triggers>

 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

please someone can helpme!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue, the problem is that the project was migrated from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.5 and in the web.config file the migration auto generated the following lines:

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy"/>
<pages clientIDMode="AutoID" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5"/>
```

So I removed it and all is working fine!!!

I leave the link to explain the "xhtmlConformance" tag: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228268(v=vs.100).aspx